# What is difference between $stateProvider and $rootProvider in angular js?

Tags: angularjs

i am new to angularJS UI application development.

I develop one application in this i use $rootProvider,but my client want to change that $stateProvider  into $stateProvider.

can you tell me the difference between tbetween $stateProvider and $rootProvider.

please help me to go forward.

Thanks&Regards,
srinivasarao.ch

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure that it is $rootProvider and not $routeProvider ?

This link will certainly help you:

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

Read the READ ME file.It will tell you to how to replace from $stateProvider.